# Match portion of string and retrieve not-near number regex

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my string:

```
setLocation('http://www.example.com/shop/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5mYXJtYWNpYWNhbG9pbmkuY29tL3Nob3Av/product/100/form_key/CxWB0lZZuNAENjz5/')
```

What I need ot do is match `/checkout/cart/add` and catch the number `/100/`.
This is what I have tried:

```
checkout\/cart\/add.+\/(100)\/
```

and it works, but if I try to extend it to any number:

```
checkout\/cart\/add.+\/([1-9]+)\/
```

it doesn't work anymore
[REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/nK9wQ7/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `1`  present inside the character class to `0`, so that it would match also the digit `0`.

```
checkout\/cart\/add.+\/([0-9]+)\/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use short hand notation for digits `\d`

```
checkout\/cart\/add.+\/(\d+)\/
```